# Java - how to find all currency symbols?

Tags: java

I have application are making currency exchange.
I need to set text with symbol something like that 4.25(here the symbol should be)

How i can do it? and how to put this on String?

Comment: It is also worth noting that the currency symbol is usually placed **before** the numbers in some locales - see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/numberFormat.html

Answer (score 6):

You can use `java.util.Currency` to get the currency symbol.

You can use like this,

```
Currency mDefaultCurrency = Currency.getInstance(currencyCode); // currecyCode - ISO 4217 code of the currency as per doc

finalValue = String.format("%.2f %s", value, mDefaultCurrency.getSymbol());
```

or you can user `Currency.getInstance(Locale locale)`

If you want to check all the list of supported you can use `Currecny.getAvailableCurrencies()` will give set of Currencies

Comment: note- doc for [JDK 7](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Currency.html) and for [JDK 8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Currency.html)  `Currecny.getAvailableCurrencies()` is in the both supported